# Assigning a scope to another scope Angujarjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I do not know why when I assign 1 scope to another like this:

```
$scope.test1 = "hello";
$scope.test1 = $scope.test2;
```

Sometimes if I change $scope.test2, $scope.test1 changes too, and sometimes not.
And also sometimes if I change $scope.test1, $scope.test2 changes too.

Why is this happening? maybe I am in a promise or something like that?

I do not need a solution I just want the theory of this, angular.copy is the solution.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.topicsQuery.should = $scope.appliedOrFilters;
$scope.appliedOrFilters.splice(i, 1); 
$scope.topicsQuery.should.splice(filtersToDelete[i],1);
```

Then if appliedOrFilters changes topicsQuery.should will change too and if topicsQuery.should changes appliedOrFilters will change too.

But if i put this:

```
$scope.topicsQuery.should = [];
```

nothing changes.

Does .splice change the property of an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original answer

From [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

> - Javascript is always pass by value, but when a variable refers to an
>     object (including arrays), the "value" is a reference to the object.
> - Changing the value of a variable never changes the underlying
>     primitive or object, it just points the variable to a new primitive or
>     object.
> - However, changing a property of an object referenced by a
>     variable does change the underlying object.

So, if you change the object reference it won't be updated.

```
$scope.test1 = "hello";
$scope.test2 = $scope.test1;
$scope.test1 = "world";

console.log($scope.test2); //prints "hello"
```

But if you change the property of an object, it will be updated:

```
$scope.test1 = {"title": "hello"};
$scope.test2 = $scope.test1;
$scope.test1.title = "world";

console.log($scope.test2.title); //prints "world"
```

-

### For the Updated Question

```
$scope.topicsQuery.should = $scope.appliedOrFilters;
```

All modification to the array `.should` or `.appliedOrFilters` will be saw on the 2 variables.

```
$scope.appliedOrFilters.splice(i, 1);
$scope.topicsQuery.should.splice(filtersToDelete[i],1);
```

As seen in [the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) , splice edits the array itself, so it's good.

`$scope.topicsQuery.should = [];`

Here you create a new array and assign it to `.should`.

So the `.appliedOrFilters` still points to the previous array, perfectly normal.

If you want to erase the array, you just should do

```
$scope.topicsQuery.should.splice(0, $scope.topicsQuery.should.length);
```

Comment: thanks you man, could you please check my last update, i would be very grateful